# array repeating zeros in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, data-structures

I'm learning algorithms and data structures, I'm on a question that returns a array and squares it. `sortedSquares` is the variable name.

Recently, I looked up what it meant and I got a result that said that it was just a array that repeats zeros, but it seems like I could just use `sortedSquares = []` with similar effect.

AlgoExpert is the platform that I'm using, so I cant upload all the code because of copyright stuff.

P.S. -- I'm 2 weeks into learning swift and any help would be great...thanks.

```
var sortedSquares = array(repeating: 0, from: array.count, by: 1)
```

Comment: With `var sortedSquares = []`, then `sortedSquares` is an Empty array... Print `Array(repeating: 0...)`. Depending on `array.count` it could also be an empty array...

Comment: Just to be sure, are you new to programming? Or you know programming, but are just picking up Swift and Data Structure at the same time?

Comment: I’m almost certain that `array(repeating: 0, from: array.count, by: 1)` isn’t the actual code. Please show the actual, code. (or that’s really it, it’s using a function you haven’t shown us, which you would need to do)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need an empty array (no elements) and other times you need an array pre-filled with a certain number of placeholder values. Using `Array.init(repeating:0)` will populate your array with zeros, which is not the same thing as an empty array.

```
var ints: [Int]

// after this line, print(array.count) disaplays 0, and `array.isEmpty` evaluates to true
ints = [] 

// after this line, print(array.count) returns 10, and print(array) 
// prints an array of 10 zeros. Also `array.isEmpty` evaluates to false.    
ints = Array(repeating: 0, count: 10)
```

Comment: If this answers your question you should accept it. That’s a strong norm on Stack Overflow. Up-votes are entirely optional, but you are expected to accept the first answer that solves our problem (or the best answer if a later answer is substantially better.)